# Set custom 'name' attribute for RadioSelect in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to set custom 'name' attribute in django form.

I've been trying this kind of approach:

```
class BaseQuestionForm(forms.Form):
  question_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
  answer = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [ ... ], widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

and then setting the 'name'-attr on *answer* with:

```
form.fields['answer'].widget.name = 'new_name'
```

But this does not work, and name is always set to 'answer' as in field name. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try:

```
print form.fields['answer'].widget.name
```

I believe widget doesn't have a name (ok, I am even pretty sure ;-)).

To achieve what you want, you would have to:

```
form.fields['new_name'] = form.fields['answer']
del form.fields['answer']
```

This however will move `new_name` field to the bottom of fields if you use simply `{{ form }}` in the template (this dictionary is ordered). Django builds the form fields names in template using names of the keys.

Comment: This works pretty well. 

However is there some other way to create a database generated form in django - because this is what i'm using this code for.